# Even distribution of sticks to persons already having sticks

Tags: algorithm

There are S sticks which need to be distributed to n persons who already have some sticks. The distribution of S sticks to n persons should be such that the variance of the numbers of sticks ultimately possessed by each person is minimized.

Consider the case where S = 50 and n = 3, with the following numbers of sticks initially possessed by each person:

1. person #1 already has 5 sticks
2. person #2 already has 6 sticks
3. person #3 already has 8 sticks

The algorithm should distribute 50 sticks to person #1, person #2 and person #3 in such a way that:

1. person #1 receives 18 sticks, for a total of 23 sticks;
2. person #2 receives 17 sticks, for a total of 23 sticks;
3. person #3 receives 15 sticks, for a total of 23 sticks.

In this case, there was a distribution of the 50 additional sticks to the three available persons such that each person ultimately possesses the same number of sticks. Since the variance cannot be lower than zero, this solution is optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let S be the number of sticks to distribute and s[1], s[2], …, s[n] be the number of sticks initially held persons 1, 2, …, n.

1. compute S_total = S + s[1] + s[2] + … + s[n]
2. compute S_indiv = floor(S_total / n)
3. compute S_resid = S_total % n
4. give person i a number of sticks equal to (S_indiv - s[i])
5. choose S_resid individuals to get one extra stick each

S_total is the total number of sticks held by all persons after distributing the S additional sticks. S_indiv is the minimum number of sticks any person holds after a fair distribution. S_resid is the number of leftover sticks to be distributed in arbitrary fashion (or discarded, if all individuals should have the same number of sticks)

Comment: This does not work if the variance is not minimum in the input s[1], s[2]...s[n]

Comment: @dhinesh Counterexample?

Comment: @patrik87 S = 60, S[1] = 50, S[2] = 0, S[3] = 0, then solution has to be tweaked a bit. I did the solution in C# and uploaded in git : https://github.com/dhineshmuthuvel/NumberAllocator/blob/master/SticksSolution/SticksSolution/Allocator.cs